# Can't set table width correctly with NiceTabular* environment in NiceMatrix package

Tags: nicematrix

The sample codes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{XX}[hvlines]
    X & X \\
\end{NiceTabular*}
\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

I replace {XX} by {CC}, and the output:

[image]

Comment: When I compile your MWE, I get this error message: ./nm.tex:6: Fatal Package nicematrix Error: The column type 'X' in your environ
ment
(nicematrix)                      {NiceTabular*} is unknown.
(nicematrix)                      This error is fatal. So the error is not the definition of the width of the table, but the wrong indication of the position of the content.

Comment: I tested again. I didn't get the column type 'X' error message, but some overfull \hbox messages. The `nicematrix` version is 5.19.

Comment: And what does happen if you replace {XX} for example by {cc}?

Comment: I added the output with replace {XX} by {CC} in the question.

Comment: The TS-program I used is XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (6.0 of 2021-08-10) provides an environment `{NiceTabularX}` similar to the classical environment `{tabularx}` of the package `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{NiceTabularX}{\textwidth}{XX}[hvlines]
    X & X \\
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 7):

`{NiceTabular*}` is not equivalent to `{tabularx}` (of the eponymous package) but to the standard `{tabular*}` (certainly less efficient). So, there is no `X` column in `{NiceTabular*}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{NiceTabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccccc}
one & two & three & four & five \\
six & seven & eight & nine & ten \\
eleven & twelve & thirteen & fourteen & fifteen
\end{NiceTabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!